# Android Emulator - How to set bypass proxy

Tags: android, proxy, android-emulator

We have an application which need to connect to 2 server. One of those 2 only has pulbic ip address while other one only has private ip address. (Asking for both to have public or private now is impossible) 
To connect to public address, we need to go through our company proxy. But we need to bypass proxy to connect to the private one.

So does Android emulator provide options to set bypass proxy for certain site like browser.

Thanks and Best regards

Comment: Please refer to my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293787/how-to-bypass-proxy-for-a-specific-url-in-android-emulator)