# How to bypass proxy for a specific URL in Android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, proxy, android-emulator, emulation

I am trying to hit web services in native android application and the IP address which I am trying to hit should bypass corporate proxy.
But to connect my emulator to internet I have to set proxy in emulator.
Is there anyway I can bypass proxy for this specific IP address in emulator?

My emulator is connected to internet presently and can open sites through browser.

Comment: This might be helpful : [How to setup Android emulator proxy settings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570627/how-to-setup-android-emulator-proxy-settings)

Comment: @Shayegan: My emulator is already connected to internet. Your link shows how to connect to internet.
I need to know how to bypass this proxy for a particular URL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an intermediate proxy as Android emulator doesn't have options to set internal server URLs which don't need proxies. Try the approach suggested [here](http://tleyden.github.io/blog/2013/11/20/debugging-http-traffic-in-android-apps-with-a-proxy/). It works!